# PHPunit execute tests with wrong PDO driver in Symfony 4

Tags: docker, symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I have a PHP unit working on a remote interpreter perfectly.

It work in **all cases** without PHP Storm (I.E. using the same command in command line on the docker)

Here is the command command executed by phpstorm, and its the one i try in all situation to compare:
`php /var/www/privateapi/vendor/bin/simple-phpunit  --bootstrap /var/www/privateapi/tests/bootstrap.php --configuration /var/www/privateapi/phpunit.xml.dist --teamcity --cache-result-file=/va
r/www/privateapi/.phpunit.result.cache`

In PhpStorm when I run tests that should communicate with database, it fails because it tries to use a MYSQL driver and I use PGSQL.

Summary:

Working cases:

- In commandline, on the docker, with or without DB Tests
- In commandline, outside the docker (i.e. `docker exec -it` ... ), with or without DB Tests
- With PHPStorm, with remote interpreter, without DB Tests

Failing case:

- With PHPStorm, with remote interpreter, **with DB Tests**

Here is my conf :

**app/config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_TEST)%'
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
        mapping_types:
            container_mode: string
            network_provider: string
            sensor_status: string
            notification_channel: string
        server_version: 11
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

**app/phpunit.xml.dist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/7.5/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>src/Kernel.php</file>
                <file>src/Event/Listener/JsonToHtmlDevEventListener.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

It works well with any code, but as soon as I want to test some use case with Database like this one :

**app/tests/Security/Voter/OrganizationVoterTest.php**

```
class OrganizationVoterTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private ?OrganizationVoter $voter;
    private ?UserRepository $userRepository;
    private ?OrganizationRepository $orgaRepository;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $container = self::$container;
        $this->voter = $container->get(OrganizationVoter::class);
        $this->userRepository = $container->get('doctrine')->getRepository(User::class);
        $this->orgaRepository = $container->get('doctrine')->getRepository(Organization::class);

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testGetMinRequiredLevel()
    {
        $orga = $this->orgaRepository->findOneBy(['name' => 'orga1']);
        [....]
    }
}
```

I will get the following error :

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException : An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:106
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:166
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:154
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:28
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:362
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:1443
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:890
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php:718
 /var/www/privateapi/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:193
 /var/www/privateapi/tests/Security/Voter/OrganizationVoterTest.php:32
```

Comment: in phpunit xml add another `<env ...>` to the ones you already have that has the required `DATABASE_URL_TEST` as `name`, should be sufficient

Comment: Hi @Jakumi, thanks it was that.
Now I putted the exact string in this env (postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres/privateapi_test) : I am getting 
```could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve```
I don't understand, is it really running the command inside the container ?
Cause the continer does know "postgres"...

Comment: I figured out.
I am know using 
```postgresql://postgres:postgres@docker.for.win.localhost:5432/privateapi_test``` (considering there is a mapping port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jakumi, i found out that I needed to manually add the env Var `DATABASE_URL_TEST`.

Because I am using WSL I should use this as the host `docker.for.win.localhost`.